# Autofill Proxy requirements webview2

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I'm creating a custom internet browser using winforms and webview2 and whenever I search for something when using say a school internet it has a proxy box asks for my username and password.
How can I autofill this box every time it opens

Comment: Ideally you should be able to the proxy in options, but it doesn't seem to have been fixed yet: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/193#issuecomment-663046277

Comment: Is the dialog that pops up a javascript dialog?

Comment: not completely sure if its Javascript, It only pops up if I 1. Haven't connected to that internet today. or 2. I reconnected to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView2 webView21 = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();

var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=\"" + proxy.Address.Host + ":" + proxy.Address.Port + "\"";
var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options);
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);

webView21.CoreWebView2.BasicAuthenticationRequested += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2BasicAuthenticationRequestedEventArgs>(delegate (object? sender, CoreWebView2BasicAuthenticationRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    var _credential = proxy == null ? null : proxy?.Credentials as NetworkCredential;
    if (_credential != null)
    {
        e.Response.UserName = _credential.UserName;
        e.Response.Password = _credential.Password;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [command-line options for proxy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-cmdline-options-proxy-settings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#command-line-options-for-proxy-settings). You can set those options through [AdditionalBrowserArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.additionalbrowserarguments?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of an instance of [CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and pass to [CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment.createasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) when creating the CoreWebView2.

For example:

```
WebView2 webView21 = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
    options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=\"proxyhostname:8000\"";
    var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options);
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);

    webView21.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(webView21);
    webView21.Source = new Uri("Https://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Here are the options that you can use:

- `--no-proxy-server`: Not to use proxy.
- `--proxy-auto-detect`: Automatically detect proxy configuration.
- `--proxy-server=<scheme>=<uri>[:<port>][;...] | <uri>[:<port>] | "direct://"`: Use custom configurations.
- `--proxy-bypass-list=(<trailing_domain>|<ip-address>)[:<port>][;...]`: Bypass any specified proxy for the specified semicolon-separated list of hosts.
- `--proxy-pac-url=<pac-file-url>`:  To use the PAC file at the specified URL.

To see more description and example about those options see:

- [How to use Microsoft Edge command-line options to configure proxy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-cmdline-options-proxy-settings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#command-line-options-for-proxy-settings)

Comment: OP wants to set username and password. How does he do that?

Comment: I guess the username/password box which is being asked in the OP's question is a basic authentication/authentication challenge window, or may be a HTML login page. OP needs to provide more details/MCVE (if possible) for the question.

Comment: All the mentioned seems work well. However, (and what I totally cannot find anywhere) that's not quite clear how to use proxies which require authentication (like the way user:pass@ip:port, or ip:port:user:pass). I've tried several ones, and none works for me. I receive ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES all the time! Any clue?